# Search for one key in multi-level JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I receive JSON output from several different web services. I need to obtain some token data from each service however it's in a different array each time. E.g.:

Service 1:

```
{
    "service_name": "service1",
    "service1_data": {
        "token_data": "WSD123456789"
    }
}
```

Service 2:

```
{
     "service_name": "service2",
     "service2_data": {
         "token_data": "QSD76662345"
     }
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to search for the value of "token_data" no matter where in the arrays it may be. At the moment I have to get it manually like so:

```
json1["service1_data"]["token_data"]
```

If theres a simple way to do this it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) (similar to [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)) to locate your element. This is included inside [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support).

Comment: @Uwe Keim Better than my suggestion, why not post it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Does the position of token_data in the array depth change all the time or is it constant?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the JSON to XML and then use an xpath like '//token_data' to find the token, assuming a simple string search or regex is not an option.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
    var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(stream, quotas);
    var xml = XDocument.Load(jsonReader);
}
```

Xpath info can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/en)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you could use JSONPath.

In your scenario, `$.service1_data.token_data.*` should get you all the values you want.

This works only if the depth of token_data in the array is always the same.

Comment: Hi, but the mid-level array isn't always called service1_data. It can be service2_data or even "thisisadataarray". Would this still work?

Answer (score 0):

The [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/json) package - available on NuGet `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` allows you to walk Json objects using LINQ expressions.

```
var jsonText = @"{
    ""service_name"": ""service1"",
    ""service1_data"": {
        ""token_data"": ""WSD123456789""
    }
}";

var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonText);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(jsonObject["service1_data"].Value<string>("token_data") == "WSD123456789");
```

See [the JToken reference](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to learn how to retrieve values from Json.